# Selecting projects that does not have LICENSE file

Tags: google-bigquery

For research purposes, I want to select github projects that do not have any LICENSE related file in the root this. With this code I can select the LICENSE files,

`SELECT repo_name 
FROM [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.files] 
WHERE path = "license"`

But how can I express the "does not have" sentence?

Comment: WHERE path != "license" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Felipe Hoffa's suggestion, I ended up with this query:

`SELECT url
FROM [ghtorrent-bq:ght.projects]
WHERE url not in
(SELECT CONCAT("https://api.github.com/repos/", repo_name)
FROM [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.licenses])
limit 100000`

I have to limit otherwise bigquery says that it cannot parse all this data.

Answer (score 0):

Every repo on the [bigquery-public-data:github_repos] dataset has a LICENSE file, as only repos which have a known and detectable license have been mirrored.

Depending on your goal, you might find the data you want on:

- https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/githubarchive:month.201610
- https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/ghtorrent-bq:ght.projects

and look for projects not in https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/bigquery-public-data:github_repos.licenses.